# Dynamic, table-driven SSIS data flow tasks

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to consolidate an inherited set of SSIS packages into a single table-driven package but I am having problems getting around the need to map input and outputs at design time.

**The problem:**

Everyday, we need to copy ~40 tables from a production server to a couple other production servers and a couple dev/test servers.  The target table and the destination table will always be the same, in name and structure.  The intent here is to have the same package run everytime, and control its behavior by making changes to it's driving configuration table.

Also, it is worth noting that at any given time, one server may not want Table#n populated, and I would like to just be able to turn that specific table off in the configuration table.

**Example flows:**

Prod1\DB\Table1 needs to be sent to Prod2\DB\Table1, Prod3\DB\Table1, Dev1\DB\Table1, and Test1\DB\Table1.

Prod1\DB\Table2 needs to be sent to Prod2\DB\Table2, Prod3\DB\Table2, Dev1\DB\Table2, and Test1\DB\Table2.

Etc... to ~Table40.

** The progress:**

So far, the package I've developed so far is like follows:

1. Query the server\database with the configuration table for servers with active table transfers.
2. Pass this list of servers to a Foreach loop container.
3. For each server, build the connection string and query the configuration table for a resultset of tables to populate.
4. Pass the resultset to another Foreach container.
5. For each table, build the query to be used in the source component of the data flow task.
6. Use the query, as stored in the variable as the data source.
7. Use the dbTable variable to point the destination to the correct table.

This is where I am getting stuck, I have been unable to get around having to map input/output columns even though I know that the tables are and will always be the same between the different servers\databases\tables.

**The questions:**

1. Is there a way to get around having to map the input/output columns for the specific tables/data flow tasks I will be moving/using, given that there are so many tables and some tables may be turned off for a given server on any given day?
2. Does anyone have a better design idea besides programatic generation of the package at runtime?  I have the ability to write this, but our team really can't spare the resources at this time.
3. Is this problem better solved with a scheduled backup and deployment job rather than an SSIS package?

I apologize if I've broken any etiquette with this post, let me know and I will try to fix it, thank you for any and all thoughts on the matter!

Comment: I could have also closed this as a duplicate of any number of questions asking whether you can do dynamic mappings in SSIS. The answer is No. A data flow is tightly bound to the metadata and therefore the sins you could commit in DTS cannot be done here

Comment: Instead, the referenced duplicate is the approach you should take. It will build out as many packages as you specify based on the results of the query there. If your source changes, new column added, data type changed etc, or you learn of a new requirement, you just regenerate packages and everything gets fixed. It's a thing of beauty

Comment: Thanks @billinkc, I am fairly new to SSIS and so I wasn't sure I was dealing the exact same issue in the other questions I found.  The referenced duplicate was very helpful, thanks.